# Error al traer los datos

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando una consulta, captando el dato desde una celda de un `DataGridView`. Cargo los datos en el `DataGridView`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando debugeo veo que si funciona lo que hago:

Veo si lo pasó:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me trae los datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el problema está ahí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

El `datos[0]` me trae el `Count = 1`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Clase **Certificados**:

```
public class Certificados
{
    public string Agencia { get; set; }
    public string Cobrador { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public double Titulo { get; set; }

    public int cantCuo { get; set; }

    public Nullable<double> Endoso { get; set; }
    public string Domicilio { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public string Piso { get; set; }
    public string Dpto { get; set; }
    public string Mono { get; set; }
    public string DniTipo { get; set; }
    public double DniNumero { get; set; }
    public string Barrio { get; set; }
    public string Localidad { get; set; }
    public string Provincia { get; set; }
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    public string Celular { get; set; }
    public string acidzona { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Sorteo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Cuota { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")]
    public Nullable<decimal> Monto { get; set; }

    public string Letras { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> CodigoPostal { get; set; }
    public string barras { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> deuda { get; set; }
    public string Solicitud { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Vencimiento { get; set; }

    public string Estado { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}")]
    public Nullable<double> ValNom { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}")]
    public Nullable<double> PlanAntes { get; set; }

    public string DescPlanActual { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public System.DateTime FechaSorteo { get; set; }

    public string suscriptor { get; set; }

    public string cel { get; set; }

    public string asesor { get; set; }
    public string nombreCobrador { get; set; }
    public string emi { get; set; }
    public Certificados() { }

    public Certificados(string nombre, double dni)
    {
        this.Nombre = nombre;
        this.DniNumero = dni;
    }

    public Certificados(string person, string domicilio, string numero, string dpto, string piso, string localidad, string barrio, string provincia,
        double dni, string soli, string em, string codigo, decimal? monto, string desc, double? valnom, string tel, string barras, int cuo,
        string cel, string ase, string cob)
    {
        this.Nombre = person;
        this.Domicilio = domicilio;
        this.Numero = numero;
        this.Dpto = dpto;
        this.Piso = piso;
        this.Localidad = localidad;
        this.Barrio = barrio;
        this.Provincia = provincia;
        this.DniNumero = dni;
        this.Solicitud = soli;
        this.emi = em;
        this.Codigo = codigo;
        this.Monto = monto;
        this.DescPlanActual = desc;
        this.ValNom = valnom;
        this.Telefono = tel;
        this.barras = barras;
        this.cantCuo = cuo;
        this.cel = cel;
        this.asesor = ase;
        this.nombreCobrador = cob;
    }

    public string toString()
    {
        return Nombre.ToString() + " " + Domicilio.ToString() + " " + Numero.ToString() + " " + Dpto.ToString() + " " + 
            Piso.ToString() + " " + Localidad.ToString() + " " + Barrio.ToString() + " " + Provincia.ToString() + " " + 
            DniNumero.ToString() + " " + Solicitud.ToString() + " " + emi.ToString() + " " + Codigo.ToString() + " " + 
            Monto.ToString() + " " + DescPlanActual.ToString() + " " + ValNom.ToString() + " " + Telefono.ToString() + " " + 
            barras.ToString() + " " + cantCuo.ToString() + " " + cel.ToString() + " " + asesor.ToString() + " " + 
            nombreCobrador.ToString();
    }
}
```

Así estoy tomando el valor del `DataGridView`:

```
    private void datos48()
    {
        Certificados certificados = new Certificados();

        const int nroColumna = 1;
        certificados.DniNumero = 0;


        foreach (DataGridViewRow columna in dtgSuscriptor.Rows)
        {
            certificados.DniNumero = Convert.ToDouble(columna.Cells[nroColumna].Value);
        }
        
        ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
        var datos = conexionSQL.cargarDatosPDF(certificados);

        //Objeto para leer el pdf original
        PdfReader oReader = new PdfReader(pathPDF);
        //Objeto que tiene el tamaño de nuestro documento
        Rectangle oSize = oReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
        //Documento de itexsharp para realizar el trabajo asignandole el tamaño original
        Document oDocument = new Document(oSize);

        //Creamos el objeto en el cual haremos la inserción
        FileStream oFS = new FileStream(pathPDFCompleto, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        PdfWriter oWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(oDocument, oFS);
        oDocument.Open();

        //El contenido del pdf, aquí se hace la escritura del contenido
        PdfContentByte oPDF = oWriter.DirectContent;

        //Propiedades de nuestra fuente a insertar
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        oPDF.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
        oPDF.SetFontAndSize(bf, 22);

        //Se abre el flujo para escribir el texto
        oPDF.BeginText();
        //Le damos posición y rotación al texto
        //La posición de Y es al revés de como estamos acostumbrados

        //mitad arriba - nombre
        oPDF.SetTextMatrix(210, oSize.Height - 213);
        oPDF.ShowText(datos[0].suscriptor);

        //mitad arriba - domicilio
        oPDF.SetTextMatrix(160, oSize.Height - 243);
        oPDF.ShowText(datos[0].domicilio);

        //mitad arriba - localidad
        oPDF.SetTextMatrix(410, oSize.Height - 243);
        oPDF.ShowText(datos[0].localidad);

        //mitad arriba - provincia
        oPDF.SetTextMatrix(160, oSize.Height - 265);
        oPDF.ShowText(datos[0].provincia);

        oPDF.EndText();
        PdfImportedPage page = oWriter.GetImportedPage(oReader, 1);
        oPDF.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        oDocument.NewPage();

        //Cerramos los objetos utilizados
        oDocument.Close();
        oFS.Close();
        oWriter.Close();
        oReader.Close();
    }
```

En el botón:

```
    private void btnImprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datos48();
    }
```

Comment: Qué valor tiene `datos[0]`?

Comment: `datos[0]` me dice `Count = 1` @Bicho

Comment: Existe suscriptor?

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, estaba haciendo mal el método de la clase conexionSQL :)

Comment: Por favor, pon la solución **como una respuesta**, indicando qué ajustaste en la clase que mencionas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues bien, mi error estaba en la forma de traer los datos en mi clase **ConexionSQL**, lo que hacía era esto:

```
string suscriptor = dr["persona"].ToString();
```

Y lo cambié por:

```
Certificados cer = new Certificados();
cer.suscriptor = dr["persona"].ToString();
```

Con esta modificación conseguí traer los valores que necesitaba usando esto:

```
datos[0].suscriptor
```